# Find Everything between user defined opening and closing tag

Tags: php

how can i find Everything between opening {table} and closing tag {/table}
e.g

```
{table} This is <strong>table</strong> {/table}
```

I want all html tags should be removed within {table} tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback('@{table}(.*?){/table}@',
    function ($mat) { return strip_tags($mat[0]); }, $s);
```

For something like

```
aa {table} This is <strong>table</strong> {/table} kk
```

this will give

```
aa {table} This is table {/table} kk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input  = '{table} This is <strong>table</strong> {/table}';
$output = '';
preg_match('/\{table\}(.*?)\{\/table\}/', $input, $matches);

if ( !empty($matches[1]) ) {
    $output = stripslashes($matches[1]);
}
```